# TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined Angular SSR

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm trying to implement SSR in my Angular 10 Application.

While running `npm run serve:ssr`, I'm getting the below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.getFileName (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:146:2983341)
    at bindings (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:146:2982295)
    at Object.fkvp (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:146:1040990)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:1:295)
    at Object.WjXW (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:146:306026)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:1:295)
    at Object.IwPw (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:141:827463)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:1:295)
    at Object./PQX (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:1:648775)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/a1410978/Desktop/workspace/asfc-shell/dist/server/main.js:1:295)
```

I've searched all over and could not find any solutions for it.

I'm not sure how to fix this error while running my server.

Below is my **server.ts**

```
....
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/asfc-web/browser');
const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
const window = domino.createWindow(indexHtml);

global['window'] = window;
global['document'] = window.document;

import { AppServerModule } from '../../projects/asfc-web/src/main.server';
....

app.use(helmet());

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModule,
}));

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.set('views', distFolder);

app.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
});

...
function run (): void {
  // Server
  let server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    winston.info(`
  ASFC Shell listening on: http://localhost:${server.address()}${ACCESS_PATH}
  ENVIRONMENT: ${ENV}
  `);
  });
}

declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}
```

Please guide me.